# Trying to interpret mod_rewrite - could use some information

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok, I'm not amazing with mod_rewrite. I'm trying to get better - but it is a little difficult to read sometimes.

Anyway, I'm trying to setup a test site for a client, and move over their current live site. I've been reading on mod_rewrite, but it is difficult to find an easy to understand source for me.

They have a fairly extensive .htaccess file.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^clientdomain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

The way I read this is -

if the domain starts with clientdomain.com, redirect to a server with HTTPS enabled - am I reading that correctly?

The next is this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)clientdomain2.COM [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ clientdomain/template.php?pid=49 [R,L]
```

As far as I can tell, this says that if the domain is clientdomain2.com, to direct to clientdomain and go to the template.php page with a GET argument of pid=49 - correct?

Finally, I have no freaking clue what this means at all:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/|\.php|\.html|\.htm)*$ index.php?phpinc=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

It looks like the first part is stripping away any and all .php, .htm, and .html - correct?

Any advice on this, or sources for an easy to understand treatment of mod_rewrite would be VERY welcome

Comment: It's not only about mod-rewrite directives, it's more about `regular expressions`. Check this [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) for both and [this one](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html) for `regex` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the domain starts with clientdomain.com, redirect to a server with HTTPS enabled - am I reading that correctly?

Almost, it should be read:

"If the domain starts with `clientdomain.com` **AND** the request is an HTTPS request, then 302 redirect to the server defined by the `ServerName` directive (probably in vhost config) but with a `www.` in front of it with the same request and using HTTPS."

> As far as I can tell, this says that if the domain is clientdomain2.com, to direct to clientdomain and go to the template.php page with a GET argument of pid=49 - correct?

No, this checks for anything with `clientdomain2.COM` in it, case insensitive (`NC` flag), and 302 redirects it to the same host and protocol and the URI `/clientdomain/template.php?pid=49`. Because it doesn't contain a protocol and hostname (e.g. `http://clientdomain2.com/`), it will redirect to the same host and protocol that the request was made with, only the URI changes. Example: The request is for `http://www.clientdomain2.com/something/foo` and the redirect is made to `http://www.clientdomain2.com/clientdomain/template.php?pid=49`.

> It looks like the first part is stripping away any and all .php, .htm, and .html - correct?

This is a "routing" type of rule. These rules are usually *after* redirecting rules since it's sort of a catch-all. It is saying:

1. The request isn't for an existing file
2. The request isn't for an existing directory
3. The requested URI doesn't start with `/index.php`
4. The requested URI ends with one of the following extensions (case insensitive, `NC` flag): `php`, `html`, `htm`, or the requested URI is simply `/`, or the requested URI has no extensions at all (the `/[^.]*` expression). It looks like this condition is to prevent the rule from being applied to things like scripts, images, css styles, etc.
5. If conditions 1-4 are met, then internally rewrite the request, without any extensions if they exist, to `/index.php` with the query string parameter named `phpinc` with the value of the requested URI (sans extensions). Any existing query string parameters are appended to the end (`QSA` flag).

The last rule there is to set an environment variable `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` to whatever was in the `Authorization` header. This gets picked up via `$_SERVER` variables in the php script.